# How to do validation for set boolean and double

Tags: java, validation, setter

I just start to learn java recently, i got 1 problem about the validation for setter, refer below is the setter validation for string type , what should i should i write to do the setter validation for boolean and double?  below is the code i wrote for string.

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private boolean isNew;
    private double bonus

    public Person(）
    {
    this("Unknown","unknown",true,0.0);    
    }

    public Person(String id,String name,boolean isNew,double bonus)
    {
        
    setId(id);
    setName(name);
    setIsNew(isNew);
    setBonus(bonus);

    }

    public getId()
    {
    return id;
    }

    public getName()
    {
    return name;
    }

    public setId()
    {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public setName()
    {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public void display()
    {
    System.out.println("Id：" + id);
    System.out.printoutln("Name:" + name); 
    }  
    // setter validation for string
    public void setName(String name)
    {
    if(name == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A valid name must be provided ");
    }
    name = name.trim();
    if(name.length() ==0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name must not be blank ");
    }
    this.name = name;
    }
    // setter validation for id
    public void setId(String id)
    {
    if(id == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A valid id must be provided ");
    }
    id = id.trim();
    if(id.length() ==0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Id must not be blank ");
    }
    this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I just start to learn java recently, i got 1 problem about the validation for setter, refer below is the setter validation for string type , what should i should i write to do the setter validation for boolean and double?

Comment: What is an invalid `double`? Or an invalid `boolean`?

Comment: not 0.0? invalid boolean not equal to 'true' or false'

Comment: There's no general rule that says a double cannot be 0.0. That's for *you* to decide based on *your* requirements. If that's what you need you already know how to check whether a string is null or empty, so you can surely write something that checks whether a `double` equals 0.0 and throw an exception if that's the case.  And there's literally no way a `boolean` is not either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you want return value you have to declare returned type for example "public String getId()" instead "public getId()".
2. Setter expects a parameter. Example: "public setId(String id)".
3. All args constructor should looks like:

`public Person(String name, String id, boolean isNew, double bonus) {this.name = name; this.id = id;this.isNew = is;this.bonus = bonus; }`

4. For boolean argument constructor expect value. If you want validate something you can change type to Boolean and handle NullPointerExeption.
   Or create custom exception:

   ```
   public class MyWrongBooleanException extends RuntimeException 
    {
    public IncorrectFileExtensionException(String errorMessage, Throwable err)
    {
    super(errorMessage, err);
    }
    }
   ```